# I am unable to pass a variable in IF statement

Tags: if-statement, awk

The objective of this script is to check for file with similar names in a rpt1 rpt2 txt files. Here Rpt1 and rpt2 are two txt files where i ahve already extracted the directory (fold1 fold3 ) info in previous part of the program. I have ran this script. Its throwing error.

Error: 
5.sh[74]: syntax error at line 92 : `"' unmatched

what does 74 mean? what does 92 mean ? Can please help me solve this issue. 
thanks in advance.

```
72  line=1
74  while [ $line -le $total1 ]
75  do
77  memr=$(sed -n "${line}p" rpt1.txt| awk '{print $3}')
80  if [ $memr != 512 ]; #checking for file
82  then
84  line2=1 #count value for rpt2
86          while [ $line2 -le $total2 ]
87          do
88          (
90          search=$(  sed -n "${line}p" rpt1.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}' )
92          if [ "$(grep "$search" "awk -F"/" '{print $NF}' rpt2.txt)" != ''        ]
93          then
94          if [ "awk '/$search/ {print $3}' rpt1.txt" -eq    "awk '/$search/ {print $3}' rpt2.txt" ]
95          then
96          echo "$search is duplicate" "location 1 is" "$(awk '/$search/' {print $4}' rpt1.txt)"
98          "$(awk '/$search/' {print $4}' rpt2.txt)"
```

100          fi
   101          fi
   102          echo "$search" " is unique file"
   103          line2=`expr $line2 +1`
   104          done
   106          line1=`expr $line1 +1`
   107          done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, 92 is the line where it's complaining about unmatched double quotes, and rightly so - there are *seven* double quotes on that line so you definitely have a problem there.

I'm not entirely certain why you have one immediately preceding the `awk` command - that seems out of place to me.

Comment: this is the first time i am straight away using awk and grep in IF statement it self. On top of this i am calling pattern and file time too in grep. 
i have fixed the Double quotes. But there are some other errors that are stil throwing.

Comment: @user2182951, then they would be a suitable subject for _another_ question :-)

Answer (score 0):

92: are you trying to look into `rpt2.txt` for occurences of `$search` in last field ?

if yes, then you can rewrite the line as follows:

```
if [ "$(awk -F'/' '$NF=="'"$search"'"' rpt2.txt)" ] ;
```